# Magento 2.3 Can't view module's front end page output?

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, development, magento2.3

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to module development for Magento 2, and I need some help: I've started developing a module (for testing purposes) on a localhost installation of Magento 2.3. Now, I think I've done everything right (I created the module.xml, the registration.php, ecc..) and I'm trying to output a simple message on the frontend. This is my code:

1. routers.xml

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
       <route id="test" frontName="test">
           <module name="Ronk_Test" />
       </route>
   </router>
   ```
2. test_index_index.xml

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
       <title>Ronk Test Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Ronk\Test\Block\Test" name="testPage" template="Ronk_Test::test.phtml" />
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
   ```
3. test.phtml

```
 echo $block->getTest(); 
 echo __('This is a text.')
```

4. Index.php

```
namespace Ronk\Test\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
 * Contact index controller
 */
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Ronk\Test\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param \Ronk\Test\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        \Ronk\Test\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        if (!$this->helper->isEnabled()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }
        return parent::dispatch($request);
    }

    /**
     * Ronk Test Page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Ronk Test Page'));
        if (!$resultPage) {
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            return $resultForward->forward('noroute');
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

5. Data.php

```
namespace Ronk\Test\Helper;

/**
 * Ronk Test helper
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * Path to store config if extension is enabled
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED = 'ronk/basic/enabled';

    /**
     * Check if extension enabled
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_ENABLED,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

I followed a guide, of course (being new to this) and I can't seem to understand what am I doing wrong. 
Whenever i go to 127.0.0.1/magento23/test/index/index it gives me 404. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you enable your module?

Comment: Yes, Everything is enabled

Comment: could you please remove      `dispatch(RequestInterface $request)` function from `Ronk\Test\Controller\Index\ Index` and check? i have suspect that it is returning false

Comment: Tried, it still gives me 404 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`routes.xml` file must be present in `Ronk/Test/etc/frontend` directory. Also make sure the file name is not `routers.xml`.

Comment: ...I'm an idiot... I called it routers. Sorry and thanks a lot, I would never had seen it :(

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, it's working wonders now, thanks a lot!

Comment: happy to know that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure whether this is the problem but if you create a reference to your block like so:

```
$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Ronk\Test\Controller\Index\Index');
```

and then you can use `$blockObj`to access the block methods like `$blockObj->getTest()`